C#.Net Chart control. I need to show the Label of the bar in the middle of the bar not on top
C# & .NET Chart control. I need to show the Label of the bar in the middle of the bar not on top.
To get the original photo below, I have set the series flag IsValueShownAsLabel to true. The desired label position is shown in the second screenshot.
Original:

Desired:


Didn't realize that I could get the result I needed by changing the ChartType from Column to StackedColumn even though I have only one item in the stack...
